# Is it possible the to lock the ISR instructions to L1 cache?

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling, cpu-cache, isr

I am running a bare metal application on one of the cores of ARM cortex A9 processor. My ISR is quite small an  I am wondering whether it would be possible to lock my ISR instructions in the L1 cache? Is it possible? Is there any one who would explain some drawbacks of doing it?

Regards,
N

Answer (score 3):

The Cortex-A9 does not support L1 cache lockdown (neither instructions nor data).

The drawback is that taking large chunks of the cache away (lockdown is usually done on a granularity of entire cache ways) decreases performance for everything else in the system.

Not to mention the fact that if your ISR is indeed small, and it is called frequently, it is somewhat likely to be in the cache anyway.

What is the benefit you were expecting to gain from doing this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My Sole purpose is conducting experiments to gain insight on the factors which affect the jitter in the interrupt latency. Iam trying  to optimize interrupt latency for hard real time application. As far as your second argument, I am not doing anything in that core, it is just handling my critical interrupt( may be i will add some background processing later), so performance of the rest of the system does not matter ( since L1 is private to the core).

Comment: http://www.altera.com/literature/wp/wp-01190-real-time-socs.pdf according to this document ( page 9 1st paragraph), It says it is possible, hence i was wondering. Otherwise searching online, i could only find cache locking for L2 cache.

Comment: Some SoCs have TCM (Tightly Coupled Memory), there you could place your ISR code permanently. It often has the same or just little better latency than L1, but usually a lot better than L2.

Comment: I've checked the Altera document, on page 9 it only suggests that the code should be smaller than the L1 icache, so it can stay there all the time. On page 11 they suggest to lock it in L2 if the code is bigger than L1.

Comment: If I would catch myself trying to optimize the interrupt latency in order to meet the hard real-time constraints, then I would consider re-designing the SW arch.

Comment: @Nuetrino: well, but if you are running nothing other than the ISR, then what would you gain by locking it the cache? It would just be there anyway.

Comment: @unixsmurf I might have one more lower priority Inter processor interrupt to the other core for communication. so that is the reason i told I might add some background processing which i am not sure now.

Comment: @adi like i said this is a study about various sources which cause jitter in the interrupt latency ( just for experimental purpose).

Comment: @Masta79 yes you are correct. I misread it. If my background task and ISR are small enough, then they will always be in cache. It was stupid of me. Thanks Masta79 and unixsmurf.

Comment: Cool. Interesting topic then :) Let us know about the results :)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is the perfect fit for fast interrupt. (FIQ)

You only have to assign the last interrupt number for that particular ISR.

While other interrupt numbers are just vectors, the last number branches directly to the code area, thus saving one memory load plus interlock. You save about three cycles or so.

Besides, i-cache lockdown isn't as efficient as d-cache lockdown.

CA9 doesn't support L1 cache lockdown anyway (for some good reasons), so don't bother.

Just make sure the ISR is cache line aligned for maximum efficiency. (typically 32 or 64byte)

Comment: Jake, "What do you mean when you say assign the last interrupt number to the ISR" - do you mean that because FIQ handler does not need a branch instruction since it is the last exception in the vector table ( like defined in asm-vector.s) ?. How do i make sure that ISR cache aligned?. Now regarding the answer how does this make sure that my routine is in the cache ( or is it just an assumption it since i am not running anything significant other than this critical interrupt?).As far as i know FIQ is just an priority interrupt which preempts IRQ and saves some clock cycles by banking few reg.

Comment: It is hard to align the FIQ handler as the offset is encoded as `0x1c` in the ARM architecture ;-)

Comment: To be honest, I'm more of an algorithm optimizer than a system level programmer. That being said, I might be wrong on interrupt handling since I only read this on papers and never actually implemented it. Correct me if I'm wrong, FIQ is #16, right? Then it's automatically 64byte aligned. And in case you cannot assign #16 to your ISR for whatever the reason, you better put an "align" directive before the first instruction of your ISR.

Comment: However, it's not very wise to rely heavily on ISR calls since the overhead might heavily cripple the performance. Moreover, it's not essential keeping certain routines in d-cache since CA9 is quite smart fetching instructions.

Comment: @artlessnoise Aha! That kinda sucks. :) But if the ISR is less than 36bytes (not very real) or 100bytes, that's not that bad.

Comment: I meant i-cache and NOT d-cache in the comment above.

Comment: The *FIQ* suggestion is good as it will reduce latency, which is probably important to the OP.  The ARM vector tables are 32byte aligned and when a FIQ happens, the `PC=vector table+0x1c`.  As it is the last entry in the table, your complete FIQ routine maybe placed here.  Ie, no branches except the final return from exception.  As there are many banked registers, the code can often be very minimal.

Comment: @artlessnoise so I will place my FIQ handler right below the end of the vector table to exploit this right?